Windows 10 IoT not (auto)logging in after password change
We have a machine running Windows 10 Enterprise IoT, which is an identical machine used for an art installation. Since it is hooked up to a large LED screen and (re)starts automatically, we have custom logon and unbranded boot enabled, meaning when you turn on the PC on the screen you see the Bios message for a few seconds and the next thing you see is the desktop. The computer turns itself on every morning via the BIOS and shuts down every evening using the Task Scheduler to trigger shutdown.exe.
This was working fine for many months.
Recently I wanted to disable the shutdown task and for disabling it you need to enter your password. Since a different company had set up the machine and we never had to enter any password, I didn't know it. After some googling I ran "net user admin newpassword" in an Admin command prompt to set a new password.
After restarting the PC you just end up on a black screen with only the mouse cursor visible.
Apparently changing the password that way does not "notify" custom logon of the new password and it still has the old password stored somewhere. This means there is a login error, but because of unbranded boot, you don't see anything, can't click anything, etc.
I tried in Safe Mode, but the same thing happens there.
Does anybody have any ideas on how to get back into the machine, short of just starting fresh?
In the meantime we are pretty certain we have the old (previous) password and I read you can just press Space, enter the old password and press enter to sort of blindly enter it, but that also did not work.
